# adding const string to a non const string does it give a const string

Tags: c++

```
void f(string& arg) { cout << arg; }
void g(const string& arg) {cout << arg; }
int main() {
    string s1 = "hello";
    const string s2 = "world"; 
    g(s1 + s2); 
    f(s1 + s2);
    }
```

Is that why calling f function like that isn't allowed?

Edit: s2 was a const to begin with i made a mistake in writing the code here.

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to bind a modifiable reference to a temporary? How would that make sense?

Comment: The temporary string resulting from adding the two together is not an `lvalue`, but....for a slightly different question, (`string s3 = s1 + s2;g(s3);f(s3);`), the answer would be no, when you add two strings together, the resulting string is **not** const.

Comment: @TimRandall Even if `s1 + s2` *was* `const`, the assigment to `s3` would still work. The difference is it wouldn't be able to move from the result, it would copy it instead. And since `s3` is non-`const` the calls to `f` and `g` both work. It's unrelated to the type of the result of `s1 + s2`.

Answer (score 7):

The result of `s1 + s2` is [not an *lvalue*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category#Non-lvalue_object_expressions), and non-const references can only be bound to [lvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category#Lvalue_expressions).